# Need to render HTML (extension) file on my website

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to render following pages on my website:

1. http://xxx/packages/most-popular-hennan-boracay-regency.html
2. http://xxx/packages/super-special-with-pickup-la-carmela.html
3. http://xxx/packages/adventures-boracay-atv-buggy-car.html

But whenever I hit these URLs in my browser, my URL is transformed in following:

1. http://xxx/packages/most-popular-hennan-boracay-regency
2. http://xxx/packages/super-special-with-pickup-la-carmela
3. http://xxx/packages/adventures-boracay-atv-buggy-car

And a 404 not found error is displayed.

I have checked my .htaccess and found nothing suspicious.

Also checked MIME Types section in CPanel.

Still unable to figure it out.

So, please help.

Comment: all browsers i.e. firefox, chrome, etc

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing in your htaccess file? Mind sharing it with us?

Comment: htaccess is there but its empty.